# Insert into a specific row multiple values with Where clause?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert two dates into a specifc row on my table using MySql but have a syntax error on Workbench (Error 1064):

```
INSERT INTO atable (Activated,Expiry) WHERE Access_Code = 'accesscode'
VALUES('$current_date','$Expiration_Date')
```

What would be the correct version for this?

Comment: INSERT statements don't have a WHERE clause.  The point of a WHERE clause is to filter existing rows but INSERT statements don't affect existing rows.  Do you want to insert a new row or do you actually want to update an existing row?  If it's the latter then you use an UPDATE statement.

Comment: I understand. This is embarrassing. Update it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
UPDATE atable
SET Activated='$current_date',
    Expiry='$Expiration_date'
WHERE Access_Code='accesscode';
```

I'm assuming you will be setting `$current_date` and `$Expiration_date` via (what looks like PHP) code.

Hope this helps.